# How can i load config file but not autoload in zf2

Tags: zend-framework2

I have some config file,they don't need use in everywhere，so i don't want it autoload,can you tell me how to load config file in controller and it can be get in serviceLocator，don't tell me to use zend\config\config, thanks。

Answer (score 1):

First off, it's not advised to ask a question and then directly say that you don't want someone to tell you about XY. What if XY would be the only way?

You could always do something like

```
$onlyNowConfig = require_once('./config/onlyNowConfig.php');
```

The current working directory of PHP is the root of your application, as it's set in your `public/index.php` via the `chdir()` function.

Other than that, there's no real harm to include the configuration inside your `module.config.php`. The `ModuleManager` will check for the existance of the `getConfig()` function inside your `Module` class. If it's existant, the Configuration will be loaded. Typically every module has a config that will be loaded. And there's no real speed (dis)advantage of outsourcing 100-200 configuration lines into a separate file. The additional I/O you'd do by only including it on those few actions you need it would actually be higher than the very little time it takes longer to merge the configuration (probably like 1ms total vs. 2-3ms I/O).

I'd advise to just include it in your `module.config.php` and you'd have it available everywhere via the `ServiceLocator`, otherwise just include/require the one config file that you need, wherever you are. The include/require parameter would never change, as the working directory of PHP will not change, no matter in what file you are (as long as you don't set it anew via chdir() - which would be highly not recommended).

Comment: Thank your suggestion(First off, it's not advised to ask a question and then directly say that you don't want someone to tell you about XY. What if XY would be the only way?),
because i use codeigniter for a long time,in codeigniter,you can load a config file like this,$this->load->config('file name'),then get the value like this,$this->config->item('key'),so i try find a scheme like codeigniter in zf2。

Comment: As i say, even though you name a reason, i don't think it's a credible one. Just bunch up all config-params alltogether in your module config and you'll have it available everywhere. WHen you don't need it, don't use it but when you need it, it's there. An additional I/O Load would just be too much overhead.

Comment: Take a look at `Zend\Config\Factory` class and in particular at the static `fromFile` method it supplies.

Comment: Thank you，may be i must change idea  from codeigniter to zf2。